# soql query to get list of queue/group names assigned to user

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am working on a query to get the names of each queue a user is in with a binding variable but am running into some issues with pulling both the queue and group.

**query:**

```
public static List<Group> getQueues(String recordId){
        return [SELECT Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN (SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE 
        UserOrGroupId = :recordId)];
    }
}
```

This works without issue but pulls **both the group and queues**.  I am looking to only pull the queue.

Any suggestions on how I can modify the query to only get queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved for groups with:

```
public static List<Group> getQueues(String recordId){

        return [SELECT Name, Type FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Regular' AND Id IN (SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :recordId)];
    }
}
```

Resolved for queues with:

```
public static List<Group> getQueues(String recordId){

        return [SELECT Name, Type FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND Id IN (SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :recordId)];
    }
}
```